# Are there any text user interfaces (TUI/ncurses) frontends for mercurial and git?

Tags: git, mercurial, tui

I am looking for a TUI (text user interface) for `mercurial` and `git`?

I need a solution for both, but not necessary the same.

Answer (score 18):

[tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/) is the one I use once in a while. That's for `git`.

Answer (score 7):

You can try [hgview](http://www.hgview.org/) for mercurial. The `hgview-curses` package is what I am using to fill the 'tig for mercurial' need.